# WebStorm2019.2.1 + Flow - cannot resolve module "XYZ" in a monorepo that uses Yarn workspaces

Tags: javascript, webstorm, flowtype, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

As per title, it seems I cannot get my `WebStorm 2019.2.1` to work with Flow in a [Yarn Workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/) environment. Most of my files imports (but weirdly not all of them) are showing this:

[image: screenshot imports not working]

As you can see, `react` import is correctly identified by Flow, while `styled-components` is not.

Note that running `yarn run flow` results in no errors.
Also, autocomplete and <kbd>Cmd + Click</kbd> on the import work perfectly.

It worths saying I have followed JetBrains guide on how to setup Flow with WebStorm ([here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-the-flow-type-checker.html)) and that the following is the content of my `.flowconfig` file:

```html
[ignore]
<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/.*config-chain/test/broken.json
<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/@mapbox/jsonlint-lines-primitives/test/fails/*
<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/react-universal-component/*
<PROJECT_ROOT>*/buildClient/*
<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/mapbox-gl/src/style-spec/node_modules/jsonlint-lines-primitives/test/fails/*
<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/mapbox-gl/src/style-spec/node_modules/@mapbox/jsonlint-lines-primitives/test/fails/*
<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/redux-persist/lib/persistReducer.js.flow

[include]

[libs]

[lints]
# This must be turned off until a fix for https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/issues/3008 is released
deprecated-utility=off

[options]
emoji=true
esproposal.optional_chaining=enable
module.name_mapper.extension='graphql' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/packages/marketing-site/internals/flow/graphqlMock'
server.max_workers=1

[strict]
```

Comment: are you on Windows? Do you have any uppercase names in the project path?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. No, I'm on `macOS Catalina 10.15.2` and I might have some uppercase names in my project path, but basically 95% of the imports are failing, so I'm pretty sure that is not the issue tbh.

Comment: indeed, must be smth different (i.e. not related to upper/lower case). I'd suggest creating a support ticket, providing a sample project the issue can be reproduced with. Flow issue that can be related: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5805